# A for loop inside a generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, generator

So recently we went over generators in the lecture, and this is my teacher's example:

```
from predicate import is_prime 
def primes(max = None):
    p = 2
    while max == None or p <= max:
        if is_prime(p):
            yield p
        p += 1
```

If we run

```
a = primes(10)
print(next(a) --> 2
print(next(a) --> 3
...
```

So this particular example of a generator uses a `while` loop and runs the function based on that, but can a generator also have a `for` loop? Like say

```
for i in range(2, max+1):
    # ...
```

Would these two operate similarly?

Comment: Yes. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo In lecture, my teacher had said one of the most common ways to use generators is in for loops, and that `while` loops should be used so as to not confuse the two in larger functions.

Comment: @Tyler: Perhaps you misunderstood? The `while` loop here is used to allow for the generator to be endless, not to distinguish between things.

Comment: @Tyler: besides, using generators *in a loop* is something different from *using a loop to in a generator*.

Comment: Aside: `max` is the name of a very handy built-in ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#max)) and so not a great name for an argument.  `upper_limit` or something would be a better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing special about generators is the `yield` keyword and that they are *paused* between calls to the generator `next()` function.

You can use any loop construct you like, just like in 'normal' python functions.

Using `for i in range(2, max + 1):` would work the same as the `while` loop, provided that `max` is set to something other than `None`:

```
>>> def primes(max):
...     for p in range(2, max + 1):
...         if is_prime(p):
...             yield p
... 
>>> p = primes(7)
>>> next(p)
2
>>> next(p)
3
>>> next(p)
5
>>> next(p)
7
>>> next(p)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```